# Different disqus comments on one page

Tags: php, wordpress, disqus

I've created a custom wordpress page where you access different matches by entering the id in the url

```
http://www.url.com/match/?id=2314
```

I want the comments to be related to a given id so each match has different comments?

Comment: So, do you need dsqus comment dynamically reloaded each time you're entering new URL?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Disqus API](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472107-using-disqus-on-ajax-sites) to reset your comments each time you select new URL:

Using Disqus on AJAX sites

> Reloading a Disqus thread within an AJAX application is possible with
>   the following code:

```
DISQUS.reset({
  reload: true,
  config: function () {  
    this.page.identifier = "newidentifier";  
    this.page.url = "http://example.com/#!newthread";
  }
});
```

See the DISQUS API Recipes repo on Github for an [example DISQUS.reset
recipe](https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/snippets/js/disqus-reset/disqus_reset.html).